# dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef fails

Tags: .net, entity-framework, command

with command:

dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

I have this error:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\NuGet.targets(130,5): error : Non è possibile caricare l'indice del servizio per l'origine https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json. [C:\Users\andrea\AppData\Local\Temp\zn5raw5v.oki\restore.csproj]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100\NuGet.targets(130,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [C:\Users\andrea\AppData\Local\Temp\zn5raw5v.oki\restore.csproj]

I have telerik component installed and seems this causes the conflict.
How to fix?

Thank you

Comment: It's not the default, so, Is it intentional/expected in your case that nuget.telerik.com is being used? Are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: I solved removing Telerik nuget feed from visual studio. After this, install command works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved removing Telerik nuget feed from visual studio. After this, install command works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `--ignore-failed-sources` option.